# Code works but then fails when I try to turn it into a function (R)

Tags: r, function

I’m trying to create a function that will take in a table of data, convert it into a df, change the row names into a separate column, then delete the row names (else the row names will appear twice), and then rearrange the columns.

I can get this to work outside of a function but as soon as I put it into a function it doesn’t work.

Example data:

```
tb <- matrix(rep(2, times=8), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
tb <- as.table(tb)
```

Getting the desired result without creating a function:

```
n <- as.data.frame.matrix(tb)   
n$Variable <- row.names(n)   #Make new column containing row names. Call it Variable.
row.names(n) <- NULL   #Get rid of row names (otherwise the row names will appear twice)
n <- n[,c("Variable", "A", "B")]  #Rearrange columns
```

Attempting to do the same as above but make it into a function:
(I get this far and then realize the output is not what I expected. I would expect df with an additional column containing the row names at this stage. Instead, I just get the row names being printed)

```
dataframe_function<-function(data) {
  n <- as.data.frame.matrix(data)
  n$Variables <- row.names(n)
  #rownames(n) <- NULL
}

df1 <- dataframe_function(tb)
df1
```

Tried various things but can't work out where I'm going wrong and can't find a solution online. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: The function isn't returning `n`. R's functions return the value of their last instruction, so put just `n` just before the end. You can also put `return(n)` but this will mean an extra function call and is not needed.

Comment: There is `rownames_to_column` in the tibble package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is incomplete. Below is all of the code previously not in a function.

```r
dataframe_function <- function(data) {
  n <- as.data.frame.matrix(data)
  n$Variable <- row.names(n)
  row.names(n) <- NULL
  n[, c("Variable", "A", "B")]  #Rearrange columns
}

tb <- matrix(rep(2, times=8), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
tb <- as.table(tb)

df1 <- dataframe_function(tb)
df1
#>   Variable A B
#> 1        A 2 2
#> 2        B 2 2
#> 3        C 2 2
#> 4        D 2 2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: "The function isn't returning n. R's functions return the value of their last instruction, so put just n just before the end. You can also put return(n) but this will mean an extra function call and is not needed."      Thank you! Feel so daft for missing that!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```r
tb<-matrix(rep(2, times=8), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
tb<-as.table(tb)

dataframe_function<-function(data){
  rn <- rownames(data)
  n<-as.data.frame.matrix(data)
  n$Variables<-rn
  rownames(n) <- NULL
  n
  
}
dataframe_function(tb)
#>   A B Variables
#> 1 2 2         A
#> 2 2 2         B
#> 3 2 2         C
#> 4 2 2         D
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>